# Avoiding property injection with Ninject

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject, prism

I keep reading that property injection is bad, but I have one usecase where I can justify it  to myself, private property injection no less. But I am wondering if it could be done differently.

So, my issue is that I'm creating (Prism) modules for an app, they need to implement the IModule interface like this

```
public class Configuration : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        ...
        //Binding here
        ...
    }
}

public class MyModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public MyModule (IKernel kernel, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _kernel.Load<Configuration>();
        //register views and the like here.
    }
}
```

It is however not optimal in my world. For instance I always have to inject the kernel and regionmanager. I can handler most of it in an abstract class like this

```
public abstract class AModule : IModule
{
    protected IKernel Kernel { get; set; }
    protected IRegionManager RegionManager { get; set; }

    protected AModule(IKernel kernel, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        Kernel = kernel;
        RegionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        Kernel.Load(CreateConfiguration());
    }

    protected abstract NinjectModule CreateConfiguration();
}

public class MyModule : IModule
{
    public MyModule (IKernel kernel, IRegionManager regionManager)
        : base(kernel,  regionManager)
    {
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        //register views and the like here.
    }

    protected override NinjectModule CreateConfiguration()
    {
        return new Configuration();
    }
}
```

But I still have to worry about the kernel and regionmanager in the constructor definition. Ideally I want to avoid writing a constructor entirely like this

```
public abstract class AModule : IModule
{
    [Inject]
    protected IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    protected IRegionManager RegionManager { get; set; }

    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        Kernel.Load(CreateConfiguration());
    }

    protected abstract NinjectModule CreateConfiguration();
}
```

This allows me to write the module like this

```
public class MyModule : AModule
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        //register views and the like here.
    }

    protected override NinjectModule CreateConfiguration()
    {
        return new Configuration();
    }
}
```

Why is this a bad way to do it, and is it even possible to do this without property injection?

Comment: Why do you need both those dependencies in all modules?

Comment: Without the kernel I cannot do DI in my views/viewmodels, and without the region manager I'm unable to register the views in the shell, so they're needed at least for GUI modules, which this implementation is for.

Comment: Who is creating the instance of `MyModule`? Who is property injecting the kernel? Who is creating the kernel? Can you show an example of how the `IRegionManager` is used?

Comment: It's a WPF application, following the Prism best practices. In short, the application developer creates the kernel, and the module developer inject in that kernel if he needs to. It is also the module developer that will register views with the region manager as follows:
`regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(Infrastructure.RegionNames.Content, () => _kernel.Get<MyView>());`

Comment: Forgot to mention that the application developer instantiate the module in the bootstrapping process, some time after the kernel has been instantiated.